# Wix. Conditionally set text property of the control

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade

I have previously installed app (version 1.0)
Now I have to change the installer to upgrade app to 2.0 version. But I want to set all data specified by user on the previous installation.

How can I conditionally fill text field in the wizard if I have all data in some properties.

Something like:

```
<?if <![CDATA[ISUPGRADE]]> ?>
      <Property Id="Account" Value="[Account_From_Registry]" />
      <Property Id="Password" Value="******" />
<?endif?>

<Control Id="Account" Type="Edit" Text="[Account]" />
<Control Id="Password" Type="Edit" Text="[Password]" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the The [WiX toolset's "Remember Property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/).

However another concern is how you plan on securing that password. It might be best to leave all of this out the install and handle it on application first run so the MSI doesn't know anything about it.